# Task stopped at: 10/04/2023, 15:58:45 UTC CgroupError: Agent could not create task's platform resources

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, ecs-taskdefinition

I am having some trouble launching a container in my EC2 instance using ECS, I have played around with the task definition quite a lot and i'm still getting this error message when I try and run the task

This is the task definition

```
aws ecs register-task-definition --family worker --network-mode awsvpc --requires-compatibilities "EC2" --container-definitions "[{\"name\":\"worker\",\"image\":\"xxxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/id89\",\"cpu\":128,\"memory\":256,\"essential\":true, \"portMappings\": [{ \"hostPort\": 80,\"containerPort\": 80}]}]
```

I am using Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.15.0-1031-aws x86_64) as my EC2 instance, the ecs-agent is all up and running - it attempts to run worker instances but they keep failing.

I have read somewhere about cgroups and setting memory on my ec2 but not sure how that's done

Any ideas?